What's wrong with my code that it is not running
what is wrong with my code it is not running
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main() {
    int c, nl = 0, nw = 0, nc = 0, state = OUT;

    printf("Enter your sentence (press Ctrl+D to stop the input):\n");

    while ((c = getchar())!= EOF) {
        nc++;

        if (c == '\n') {
            nl++;
            state = OUT;
        } 
        else if (c == ' '|| c == '\t') {
            state = OUT;
        } 
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            nw++;
        }
    }

    printf("The number of words was found to be: %d\n", nw);
    printf("The number of characters was found to be: %d\n", nc);
    printf("The number of lines was found to be: %d\n", nl);

    return 0;
}
    

I have tried changing the variable, running it on a different machine but still it is taking the input continuously and not giving me the results

When you say "not running" what do you mean by that? Please take some time to read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. Then [edit] your question to improve it.

I think they mean that in both cases it IS running, continuously, i.e. an unintened endless loop.

Do you know how to create an EOF from your terminal? What operating system are you using?

To find out the answer to Somes question you might want to change your program into a loop-free input echo, with an if to detect when you found the EOF. Or maybe with a loop, which you can accept to be endless if you cannot find out.

Have you tried ctrl-Z followed by return?

Just for testing you can also try a "normal" character for loop termination, e.g. while ((c = getchar())!= 'S') { so that a S will stop the loop. If that works, you know that your code is OK and the problem is how to input an EOF on your system

Consider using an enum for your stable variable.  It's much easier to read if you define one variable per line (and when you start looking at diffs it will make your life easier).

You want to precisely describe the problem or symptom that you want us to help you with.  "what is wrong with my code" means we have to guess what problem you need help with.  This is task not a question.  In this case your hypothesis was that your program doesn't run (great start), but you could try print something before the loop and inside the loop to convince yourself that your program is indeed running.  You could try program in a debugger to see where it's "stuck".

Your code will work correctly on Unix-like operating systems, however on MS-DOS or Windows, you can't end input stream using Ctrl+D, but you need Ctrl+Z and then Enter.
So there is no problem in your code, but the way you run it.
